# Which commands are needed to get the correct pm3d map in Gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a file (32 values for x and y-axis each ), 2D simulation output, and want to draw a palette plot in Gnuplot. I find that the pm3d map is suitable for its representation. I am using the following commands:

```
    set xrange[0:32]
    set yrange[0:32]
    set mp3d map
    splot 'contour.dat'
```

But apparently, the map is missing from the figure. It only shows the borders and other related stuff but not the main map [Image by Gnuplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOzTn.png). The figure generated from the excel plot looks like that [Excel generated picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoy6J.png). My data (screenshot of Notepad file) is given as: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTVc5.png). So my concern is what commands are needed to have that map?

Comment: The command is `set view map` rather than "set mp3d map".  To offer any help beyond that I think you will need to show us a sample of what the data file content looks like.

Comment: @Ethan thanks for the reply. Above, I have added my data picture. Please find it.

Comment: @Ethan thanks. It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `matrix` is what you need for data in that form.  Without it, the program will expect each line of the file to contain a single x,y,z value.

```
set view map
splot 'contour.dat' matrix with pm3d
```